# Can't upload product images from admin with google cloud as instance

Tags: upload

i have some issue when upload product images from admin.

[image]

i have check the permission it's set 777, but i can't still upload the images.
btw i use gcp(google cloud platform) as my instance.
maybe anyone here can help me, thank you.

[image]

Comment: try to upload image with short & different name of the image and check it.

Comment: i have rename it and try to upload, but it's still with same error. 
i rename it with back.jpg
The path "/usr/share/nginx/html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/b/a/back.jpg" cannot be renamed into "/usr/share/nginx/html/pub/media/catalog/product/b/a/back.jpg" Warning!rename(/usr/share/nginx/html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/b/a/back.jpg,/usr/share/nginx/html/pub/media/catalog/product/b/a/back.jpg): Input/output error